# UnicodeDecodeError: Swapping emoticons with text

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have collected some tweets using its API on which I need to perform text processing. Now many tweets have emoticons in them in text form, for example, :D :P etc.

This is the code for replacing slang expressions with words in python:

```
"""
exp_replace_copy.py
"""

import nltk
import re

#dictionnary to sentiment analysis

emo_repl = {
#good emotions
"&lt;3" : " good ",
":d" : " good ",
":D" : " good ",
":p" : " good ",
"8)" : " good ",
":-)" : " good ",
":)" : " good ",
";)" : " good ",
"(-:" : " good ",
"(:" : " good ",

"yay!" : " good ",
"yay" : " good ",
"yaay" : " good ",
"yaaay" : " good ",
"yaaaay" : " good ",
"yaaaaay" : " good ",    
#bad emotions
":/" : " bad ",
":&gt;" : " sad ",
":')" : " sad ",
":-(" : " bad ",
":(" : " bad ",
":s" : " bad ",
":-s" : " bad "
}

#dictionnary for general (i.e. topic modeler)
emo_repl2 = {
#good emotions
"&lt;3" : " heart ",
":d" : " smile ",
":p" : " smile ",
":D" : " smile ",
"8)" : " smile ",
":-)" : " smile ",
":)" : " smile ",
";)" : " smile ",
"(-:" : " smile ",
"(:" : " smile ",

#bad emotions
":/" : " worry ",
":&gt;" : " angry ",
":')" : " sad ",
":-(" : " sad ",
":(" : " sad ",
":s" : " sad ",
":-s" : " sad "
}

#general
re_repl = {
r"\br\b" : "are",
r"\bu\b" : "you",
r"\bhaha\b" : "ha",
r"\bhahaha\b" : "ha",
r"\bdon't\b" : "do not",
r"\bdoesn't\b" : "does not",
r"\bdidn't\b" : "did not",
r"\bhasn't\b" : "has not",
r"\bhaven't\b" : "have not",
r"\bhadn't\b" : "had not",
r"\bwon't\b" : "will not",
r"\bwouldn't\b" : "would not",
r"\bcan't\b" : "can not",
r"\bcannot\b" : "can not"    
}

emo_repl_order = [k for (k_len,k) in reversed(sorted([(len(k),k) for k in emo_repl.keys()]))]
emo_repl_order2 = [k for (k_len,k) in reversed(sorted([(len(k),k) for k in emo_repl2.keys()]))]

def replace_emo(sentence):
    sentence2 = sentence
    for k in emo_repl_order:
        sentence2 = sentence2.replace(k,emo_repl[k])
    for r, repl in re_repl.iteritems():
        sentence2 = re.sub(r,repl,sentence2)
return sentence2

def replace_reg(sentence):
    sentence2 = sentence
    for k in emo_repl_order2:
        sentence2 = sentence2.replace(k,emo_repl2[k]) #line 95
    for r, repl in re_repl.iteritems(): 
        sentence2 = re.sub(r,repl,sentence2)
return sentence2
```

I used a script for topic modelling:

```
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
import numpy as np
import nltk
import exp_replace_copy
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

class topic(object):

    def __init__(self,nbtopic=100,alpha=1,model=None,dicttp=None):

        self.nbtopic = nbtopic
        self.porter = nltk.PorterStemmer()
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.stop = stopwords.words('english')+['.','!','?','"','...','\\',"''",'[',']','~',"'m","'s",';',':','..','$']
        if model!=None and dicttp!=None:
            self.lda = models.ldamodel.LdaModel.load(model)
            self.dictionary =  corpora.Dictionary.load(dicttp)

    def fit(self,documents):

        documents_mod = [exp_replace_copy.replace_reg(sentence) for sentence in documents]
        tokens = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in documents_mod]
        tokens = [[self.porter.stem(t.lower()) for t in sentence if t.lower() not in self.stop] for sentence in tokens]        

        self.dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(tokens)
        corpus = [self.dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in tokens]
        self.lda = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus,id2word=self.dictionary, num_topics=self.nbtopic,alpha=self.alpha)

        self.lda.save('topics.tp')
        self.dictionary.save('topics_dict.tp')

    def get_topic(self,topic_number):

        return self.lda.print_topic(topic_number)

    def transform(self,sentence):

        sentence_mod = exp_replace_copy.replace_reg(sentence)
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence_mod)
        tokens = [self.porter.stem(t.lower()) for t in tokens if t.lower() not in self.stop] 
        corpus_sentence = self.dictionary.doc2bow(tokens)

    return self.lda[corpus_sentence]
```

On running this script i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "traintest_copy.py", line 27, in <module>
topic_mod.fit(np.concatenate((pos_data,neg_data)))
 File "/home/shadow/Documents/Sarcasm_Detectorr/topic_copy.py", line 24, in fit
tokens = [nltk.word_tokenize(sentence) for sentence in documents_mod]
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 106, in word_tokenize
 return [token for sent in sent_tokenize(text, language)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 91, in sent_tokenize
 return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1226, in tokenize
 return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1274, in sentences_from_text
 return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1265, in span_tokenize
 return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1304, in _realign_boundaries
 for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 311, in _pair_iter
 for el in it:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1280, in _slices_from_text
 if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1325, in text_contains_sentbreak
 for t in self._annotate_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text)):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1460, in _annotate_second_pass
 for t1, t2 in _pair_iter(tokens):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 310, in _pair_iter
 prev = next(it)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 577, in _annotate_first_pass
 for aug_tok in tokens:
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 542, in _tokenize_words
 for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any problem with the dictionaries? I can't figure out. I m using python 2.7

EDIT: code for json to csv conversion

```
import json
import csv

x = open('myjsonfile.json')
data = json.load(x)
x.close()

f = csv.writer(open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb+'))
for item in data:
    f.writerow([item["text"].replace('\n',' ').encode('utf-8')])
```

NEW EDIT: i wrote a workaround code to remove any non ascii characters in my old csv file

```
import csv

x = csv.reader(open('unamusing.csv','rb+'))
f = csv.writer(open('unamusing1.csv', 'wb+'))
out_txt=[]
for item in x:
    out_txt.append(["".join(a if ord(a)<128 else '' for a in i)for i in item])

f.writerows(out_txt)
```

Comment: Search this site for "byte 0xf0". I saw an answer about that. something to do with "hex" I believe

Comment: i have edited my question. i did search for the keyword you mentioned but can't seem to find any helpful option. please check if the edited question has any error.

Comment: Did you properly decode your input?

Comment: i have 2 json files each with a text attribute in it. I converted them to csv. Then did some preprocessing of the text, removing hashtags, friend tags etc. stored the result in npy format. then i fit it using the fit function in the topic modelling script mentioned above. the 'documents' parameter in the fit function is np.concatenate((pos_data,neg_data)) that i have passed it from another py script. i think during csv conversion i didn't decode it properly. i will look into it.

Comment: What do you mean by "please check if the edited question has any error"?

Comment: sorry. not very good with english. i mean to say if there is any error in my code that i have edited.

Comment: @syntonym i checked my csv files and yeah there are certain characters that i haven't converted, such as left double quotation mark, right double quotation mark. when i converted my json to csv, i didn't keep that in mind. can i save them as unicode characters. for example in this way: \u201cgoing to cut the grass\u201d. I have added my code for json to csv as well.

Comment: Instead of `encode` (which goes from unicode -> bytes) you should use `decode` (which goes from bytes -> unicode).

Comment: @syntonym i replaced encode with decode in json to csv code got an error `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x92' in position 69: ordinal not in range(128)`. since there were non ascii characters in my converted csv file, i wrote a workaround code to remove them. took the csv file with non ascii characters and used this snippet `out_txt.append(["".join(a if ord(a)<128 else '' for a in i)for i in item])` in my code to filter them out. encoding and decoding was confusing me a lot.

Comment: Awkward, you should at least get `'utf-8' codec can't encode character ...` but your problem is solved? If not, can you post an example input?

Comment: @syntonym sorry for replying so late. exams :/ yeah i solved my problem. i have edited the workaround solution in the question. you can check it.